# insert into a generic container doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

I'm trying to generate random numbers either of type int or double and then insert them int a type of container vector, list into a sorted order
but the problem is that insert is not working, and I don't know why, so can you help me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include<list>
#include<deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int random_gen(){
    default_random_engine re { std::random_device()() };
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
    auto r= bind(dist,re);
    int x =r();
    return x;
}



template<typename SequenceContainer>
void build_cont(const SequenceContainer& seq, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
        int gen = random_gen();
        //std::iterator<T> it=lower_bound(begin(seq), end(seq), gen);
        typename SequenceContainer::iterator it;
        it=find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), [it](){ return *it<gen;});
        seq.insert(it, gen);
    }
    for(auto i:seq)
        cout<<i<<endl;
}
int main() {
    int n=10;
    vector<int> v;
    list<int>ls;
    deque<int> deq;
    build_cont(v, n);
    build_cont(ls, n);
    build_cont(deq, n);

    return 0;
}
```

the error I'm getting right now is a linker error, so I don't know what is wrong??

Comment: If you want to insert them in order (i.e., maintain order as you insert) why not use an `std::set` or `std::multiset`?

Comment: I need the code to work with vector, list and deque

Comment: the problem I have is with the find_if and insert

Comment: What compiler takes this far enough to linker errors? `gen` is not captured, non-const iterator it can't be assigned from a find_if on a const container, etc

Comment: I'm using clang, and why gen is not captured??

Comment: @user1653150 clang++ results: http://liveworkspace.org/code/bJrb1

Comment: Mreover, you have a const container `const SequenceContainer& seq`, you won't be able to add anything there.

Comment: There are problems in random_gen and you use find_if incorrectly.

Comment: what problem? and what is wrong with find_if ?

Comment: "*I need the code to work with vector, list and deque*" No you don't. There is no reason to ever *need* that. Or at least, not a *good* reason. These containers are different for good reasons, and you shouldn't ignore those differences so casually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You can't take a const reference to SequenceContainer then try to obtain a non-const iterator or insert items into that const reference.  Remove the const.
2. You need to include 'gen' in the lambda capture clause, and it must take the value as a parameter:

   ```
   typename SequenceContainer::iterator it = find_if(
       seq.begin(),
       seq.end(),
       [gen](const int& val) { return gen < val; }
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but some other question please, if I want to insert strings instead of int but using the same function, how can I retrieve the type?

Comment: You can use "typename SequenceContainer::reference" to retrieve the type:
`typename SequenceContainer::iterator it = find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), [gen] (const typename SequenceContainer::reference & val) { return gen < val; } );`

Comment: @LeftoverPi : `SequenceContainer::reference` is already a reference, the `&` is just noise (and I assume you really want `SequenceContainer::const_reference` here) – what you have in your comment would be correct for `SequenceContainer::value_type`.